# Optimize Display for Django WebApp depending on Mobile Device vs Desktop

Tags: python, django, mobile, django-templates

What is the best way to detect the device accessing the page, and use logic to change the display depending on the browser device type?

Comment: You could use [`media queries`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) in your css file if you don't want completely different templates for mobile. And if you use them you don't need separate templates for mobile.

Comment: i want to make completely different templates for mobile.

Comment: I think this is a good question that could be better with only minor edits.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

finally i got the solution:
i use [django-mobile](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile) for this, change in `settings.py` as per requirement and made a `middleware.py` for this.

```
settings.py:(first follow `django-mobile`)

DESKTOP_TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates'),)
MOBILE_TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates/mobile'),)
```

then make `middleware.py`

```
middleware.py
from django.conf import settings

class MobileTemplatesMiddleware(object):
    """Determines which set of templates to use for a mobile site"""

    def process_request(self, request):
        # sets are used here, you can use other logic if you have an older version of Python
        MOBILE_SUBDOMAINS = set(['m', 'mobile'])
        domain = set(request.META.get('HTTP_HOST', '').split('.'))
        if request.flavour=='mobile':
            settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS = settings.MOBILE_TEMPLATE_DIRS
        else:
            settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS = settings.DESKTOP_TEMPLATE_DIRS
```

Comment: Please at least mention the original author here, instead of just copying and pasting code from another site! Your code is very similar to [this article](http://www.codekoala.com/posts/how-i-have-mobile-desktop-site-django/)

Comment: IMPORTANT UPDATE: django-mobile has seemingly been depracated since 2016 and doesn't work with the current django release

Answer (score 2):

There is a few ways to solve this problem. First is to find a way to get device info inside view and then

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def foo_view(request):
    data = Model.objects.all()
    my_template = 'template.html'
    """
    your logic for device_info
    """
    if device_info == 'mobile'
        my_template='mobile_template.html'
    return render(request, my_template, {'data': data})
```

Other way is to use [django-responsive](https://github.com/mlavin/django-responsive) and in this case you can have device_info inside base template so in this case you can have:

```
{% if device_info.type == 'phone' %}
     {% include 'templates/mobile_template.html' %}
{% else %}
     {% include 'templates/template.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

Third way is to rewrite your html/css code and use some responsive CSS frameworks like Foundation or Twitter Bootstrap

Hope it helps

Comment: Goran, I don't want to change my whole views and template for that. I am searching for the way where i can change once for template directories if it is mobile it goes to mobile templates else goes to normal templates.

Comment: Then use django-responsive app and include template from where you want {% include 'special_dir/template_name.html' %} this is exactly what you want.