# Django for loop based on mobile/screensize

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have a Django product page with a for loop that displays items als follows:

```
picture | info
info | picture
picture | info 
...
```

This is made by using an `forloop.counter|divisibleby:` loop.
The layout looks great on desktop but super weird on mobile. Is there a way to prevent this loop from running if the screensize is smaller/mobile?

Find my code below:

```
  {% for category in categories  %}
                {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:'2' %}                    
                    <a href="{% url 'academy:brandByCat_list' category.category_name %}">
                        <div class="row py-3 item-display">

                            <div class="col-md item-text">
                                <h1 class='py-3'>{{category.category_name}}</h1>
                                <p>{{category.category_info | linebreaks}}
                            </div>

                            <div class='col-md item-img'>
                                <img src= {{category.category_picture.url}} class="img-fluid category-picture">
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </a>                
                    {% else %}
                        <a href="{% url 'academy:brandByCat_list' category.category_name %}">
                            <div class="row py-3 item-display">

                                <div class='col-md item-img'>
                                    <img src= {{category.category_picture.url}} class="img-fluid category-picture">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md item-text">
                                    <h1 class='py-3'>{{category.category_name}}</h1>
                                    <p>{{category.category_info | linebreaks}}
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </a>
                {% endif %}
           {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hope it's what you looking for:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627840/optimize-display-for-django-webapp-depending-on-mobile-device-vs-desktop

Comment: I looked at it but mobile Templates are not really a thing anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Since Django templates are rendered on the server, you have no information about the user's screen size. I think you will have to use css or javascript to get the results you want.